# Error tokenizing remove pattern re.findall

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, deep-learning

[image: data]

I have error like this while cleaning text, i just tried to following code from web

```
def remove_pattern(text, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern, text)
    for i in r:
        text = re.sub(i, '', text)
    return text

df['remove_user'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(df['Comment'], "@[\w]*")
```

And I got this error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.replace` here:

```py
df["remove_user"] = df["Comment"].str.replace(r'\W+', '', regex=True)
```